# .htaccess: auto_append_file only working for PHP files, not for HTML files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm using the following code in my .htaccess file: `php_value auto_append_file included_file.html`

This is working as expected if I call `https://www.example.com/file.php` but it's not working if I call `https://www.example.com/file.html`.

It seems like `auto_append_file` is only working for `PHP` files and not for `HTML` files.

Is this an expected behavior or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: PHP directives work on PHP scripts, that's the expected behaviour. If `file.html` contains PHP code, you can configure the server to execute PHP from it. If it doesn't, the overall approach makes little sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `php_value` is evaluated by PHP, and not by Apache itself, this looks pretty usual to me. You could resolve this by letting PHP also parse all files with the extension `html`